# Text doesn't print properly in console

Tags: java

I have a simple program consisting of two methods. The first is a menu that asks if the player wants to make a suggestion or exit the game. If they choose to make a suggestion, the second method is called. The second method is suppose to print a form for the user to fill out. So it's suppose to look like this:

```
Person: 
Weapon:
Room: Library
```

Library is already filled out for the user. The rest can be filled out like this:

```
Person: Professor Plum
Weapon: Revolver
Room: Library
```

The problem is that what's printed out doesn't look like what I want. What's printed out looks like this:

```
Person: Weapon:
```

Person and Weapon are printed on the same line and the user is only able to fill out Weapons. Moreover, Room doesn't printout until Weapons is filled. Is there anyway I can make it look the way I laid out in the previous example?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

private String[] suggestions = new String[3];
private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private String room = "Library";

public void menuSelection() {
    System.out.println("Please make a selection...\n");

    System.out.println("1. Make a suggestion");
    System.out.println("2. Exit game");

    int selection = sc.nextInt();

    if (selection == 1)
        makeSuggestion();
    else 
        System.exit(0);
}

public void makeSuggestion() {
    System.out.print("Person: ");
    suggestions[0] = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Weapon: ");
    suggestions[1] = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Room: " + room);
    suggestions[2] = room;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.menuSelection();
}
}
```

Comment: you should use `System.out.println()` instead of `System.out.print()`

Comment: Using standard input and standard output isn't really compatible with the idea of "forms", which are understood as windows (or areas within windows) where you can move freely using TAB and cursor keys, type in characters and hit enter to pass the form as a unit to the app handling all that. Redesign your "non-form" as a sequence of prompts (print) and inputs via the Scanner. Or look into Java's GUI capabilities, Swing etc.

Comment: It seems that nobody who has answered the question has bothered to compile the code with their own solution to see if their answer is correct. Every single person who's answered has given the wrong solution so far. All you have to do is copy and paste the code in Eclipse and test it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sc.nextLine();` after  `int selection = sc.nextInt();`

This will give desire output

Comment: That does not print the proper output.

Comment: check now. is this give your desire output? @SeanC

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the values. Use `System.out.println()` to print those values.

```
System.out.print("Person: ");
suggestions[0] = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(suggestions[0]);

System.out.print("Weapon: ");
suggestions[1] = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(suggestions[1]);

System.out.print("Room: " + room);
suggestions[2] = room;
System.out.println(suggestions[2]);
```

**Output:**

```
Person: Professor Plum
Weapon: Revolver
Room: Library
```

Comment: That does not create the output you displayed in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println will print on a new line where System.out.print will print and the same line.  you should use System.out.println() instead of System.out.print()

Comment: That does not print the proper output.

Answer (score 0):

this is what's causing the issue:

```
int selection = sc.nextInt();
```

replace it with sc.nextLine() for example.

Comment: the value of sc.nextLine() would be a String. Perhaps Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()) would be better?

Comment: That has no bearing on the problem at all. Did you even look at the rest of the code? You're talking about the first method which doesn't even print anything. I'm talking about the second method.